# bash: elegant way to busy wait until a remote device has booted?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, ssh

In my bash script I am running an ssh command to reboot the device:

```
ssh root@device reboot
```

Immediately after that, I would like to wait for the device to boot before sending anymore ssh commands, otherwise, they would be lost.

Comment: What do you know about the device? Is it safe to rely on Linuxisms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the device runs Linux, you can poll the boot id from procfs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
max_timeout=600

if ! { device_boot_id=$(ssh root@device "cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id") \
       && [[ $device_boot_id ]]; }; then
  echo "Unable to retrieve initial boot ID -- is the device up to start with?" >&2
  exit 1
fi
if ! ssh root@device "reboot"; then
  echo "Attempt to ask device to reboot failed" >&2
  exit 1
fi

timeout_at=$(( SECONDS + max_timeout ))
until new_boot_id=$(ssh root@device "cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id") \
      && [[ $new_boot_id != "$device_boot_id" ]]; do
  if (( SECONDS > timeout_at )); then
    echo "System is still not back; giving up" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
  sleep 10
done

echo "System successfully rebooted" >&2
```

On other systems you can poll uptime -- if it goes down, then you know that the system was rebooted. (However, this is only reliable if the system has been up long enough that you're comfortable that you'll be able to connect and re-poll before the prior boot's uptime has been reached).